# SQL query DATE_FORMAT function not working as desired

Tags: php, mysql

The given mysql query not returning any data

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM type_b_services JOIN users ON
 users.userid=type_b_services.userid WHERE type_b_services.offer = 'A'
 AND type_b_services.where_you_based = 'Domestic' AND
 type_b_services.origin_country = 'United States' AND
 type_b_services.origin_city = 'seattle' AND
 type_b_services.destination_country = 'United States' AND
 type_b_services.destination_city = 'San Francisco' AND
 TRIM(DATE_FORMAT(type_b_services.travel_date,"%Y-%m")) =
 TRIM(DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-22',"%Y-%m"))
```

But this one returns 1 row

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM type_b_services JOIN users ON
 users.userid=type_b_services.userid WHERE type_b_services.offer = 'A'
 AND type_b_services.where_you_based = 'Domestic' AND
 type_b_services.origin_country = 'United States' AND
 type_b_services.origin_city = 'seattle' AND
 type_b_services.destination_country = 'United States' AND
 type_b_services.destination_city` = 'San Francisco'
```

I found that this condition breaking the data.

> TRIM(DATE_FORMAT(type_b_services.travel_date,"%Y-%m")) =
>   TRIM(DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-22',"%Y-%m"))

But the below code return 18 columns including the result of second query

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(type_b_services.travel_date, "%Y-%m") ,  
   DATE_FORMAT("2016-02-06", "%Y-%m") FROM `type_b_services` 
WHERE   
    TRIM(DATE_FORMAT(type_b_services.travel_date,"%Y-%m")) = 
    TRIM(DATE_FORMAT('2016-02-22',"%Y-%m"))
```

Comment: `type_b_services.destination_city\`` remove the backtick, on the query that does not work

Comment: that backtick is not in the original code

Comment: Any luck to solve this?